# How to run python script from php, getting and error

Tags: php, python, windows, exec

I'm sorry, I know this has been a much debated issue but I can't solve my problem and all the posts are rather old... I've been trying for days but it doesn't work.
The thing is, I just want to execute a python script from a basic php script. 
I've tried with the exec() function but have a strange error :
this is what I'm typping in php :

```
echo exec("C:\Users\paulz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python C:\wamp\www\tests\tipe\tipe.py 2>&1")
```

and I have this :

```
C:\Users\paulz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'C:\\wamp\\www'
```

a few details : 
- I'm using a windows machine,
- For the 'python.exe' file, I've seen people talking about a "c:\Python26\python.exe" path but I have nothing of this kind...
- I tried to put my file in an other place ( directory ), same error
- I tried to use system(), passthru(), shell_exec(), etc... and didn't work ( I was perhaps using them in the wrong way or with bad arguments )
- I’m using wamp so I’m working in local but I’ll have to work with a real server soon so if it changes something, I’d like to know both ways...

I just want to run this python script via php and get and array in return so if this is not the good way, just show me an other one ;)

Help please :'(

thanks !

Comment: The `\t` in the string is causing it to be interpreted as tabs `C:\wamp\www 
   ests    ipe    ipe.py`, use single quotes. https://3v4l.org/Sm2Dr

Comment: Oh my god, you just made my day better !